# rendering json nicer with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

So i have managed to get this far myself. I've got this rendering at the moment

```
{
  "ticket": [
    [
      "formatted_total_price",
      "&Acirc;&pound;66.00"
    ],
    [
      "formatted_total_price",
      "&Acirc;&pound;128.00"
    ],
    [
      "formatted_total_price",
      "&Acirc;&pound;246.00"
    ],
    [
      "formatted_total_price",
      "&Acirc;&pound;243.20"
    ],
    [
      "formatted_total_price",
      "&Acirc;&pound;242.86"
    ],
    [
      "formatted_total_price",
      "&Acirc;&pound;242.50"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "Later Owl Ticket"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "Later Owl Ticket+Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "Later Owl + Chance For VIP Upgrade"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "VIP Ticket"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "VIP Ticket + Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "Skydeck Package"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "5 Person Skydeck Table"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "7 Person Skydeck Table"
    ],
    [
      "ticket_desc",
      "10 Person Skydeck Table"
    ]
  ]}
```

Now what i'm ideally wanting is to have it look like this

```
 {
      "ticket": [
        [
          "formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;66.00"
          "ticket_desc" : "Later Owl Ticket"
        ],
        [
          "formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;128.00"
          "ticket_desc" : "VIP Ticket"
        ],
        [
          "formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;246.00"
          "ticket_desc" : "Skydeck Package"
        ],
        [
          "formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;243.20"
          "ticket_desc" : "5 Person Skydeck Table"
        ],
        [
          "formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;242.86"
          "ticket_desc" : "7 Person Skydeck Table"
        ],
        [
          "formatted_total_price" : "&Acirc;&pound;242.50"
          "ticket_desc" : "10 Person Skydeck Table"
        ],
```

I also want anything that had a + symbol after it to be ignored. as you can see my ideal dream response has it removed.

Heres the code i currently have:

```
 doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each do |text|
       if text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
         byebug
         price1 = text.to_s.scan(/\"(formatted_(?:total_price))\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         description = text.to_s.scan(/\"(ticket_desc)\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         price = price1 + description
         render json: {ticket: price}
       end
     end
```

Comment: Shouldn't ever need to manually create json. i'm not very familiar with rails but most languages have serializer for array/object to json

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CMrFcBMX <<<< this is the response. Which is the reason why i was making it into a json format. if you know of a way to make this work other than json please share C:

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/rails/jbuilder